# Does reinvestment of earnings decrease a corporation's tax

Tags: taxation, profits, accounting

There are successful companies that don't make profits, such as twitter, uber, amazon. My question is:

*Can a company just reinvest lots of money to avoid making a profit and avoid paying tax?*

From my economy 101 class I remember that you can only reinvest with money **after** paying a tax on profits.

What am I missing?

Reason for asking is that a company I was working for often refused to raise salaries on the ground of low profits while sales were great. Perhaps low profits was the result of a strategy instead of a sign of weakness.

Comment: It would be helpful to support your claim about twitter, uber, amazon with a reference - I'm not sure it's common knowledge.

Comment: @AdamBailey If it is in wikipedia, or has a lot of hits on google with a simple search query, it may be considered common knowledge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All else constant, a higher level of investments results in higher depreciation and re-valuations or "write-downs", and these higher charges to revenue result in lower taxable profits and lower taxes.

A quote...

> I remember that you can only reinvest with money **after** paying a tax
> on profits

After an investment is made, depreciation is a periodic charge so it will affect the level of taxable profit (and taxes) in not only the current period but future periods.

Comment: Does an increase in investment affect depreciation or payable taxes in the *current* period?

Comment: @Giskard depreciation is affected in the period of a new investment or an increase in total investment, so yes.